# How to use/install a GitHub commit?

Tags: github, apex, fairseq

There is a package I want to use that is implemented based on [fairseq](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq) toolkit. The package requirement says:

> Please use an earlier commit of Apex - [NVIDIA/apex@4a8c4ac](https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex/commit/4a8c4ac088b6f84a10569ee89db3a938b48922b4)

Even though I know how to install **Apex**, I'm not sure if I understand what it means to use an earlier commit of a package and how exactly I can use the commit (e.g., how can I install a commit of a package)? Does it just mean a specific version of that package? And if so, how can I find that specific version from a commit?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out how to install a specific commit! Here is how in case anyone else is wondering:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/nvidia/apex
$ cd apex
$ git checkout <commit hash>
$ pip install ... # whatever install command
```

So for example, if there is a specific commit for a GitHub repo like the following (in my case, I was trying to use an earlier commit of Apex):

```
   https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex/commit/4a8c4ac088b6f84a10569ee89db3a938b48922b4
```

After cloning the repo, you run:

```
git checkout 4a8c4ac088b6f84a10569ee89db3a938b48922b4
```

Using this command, you in fact change the HEAD to a specific commit. Then, you install your package using whatever command you have.